# On page load the background image starts squish then expands

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't understand why this [page](https://dawnclark.net/how-the-magic-happens/) starts with the image squished the expands to the right viewport size. I don't see anything on the css that would make it behave like that.

I do have this script which basically make sure that the canvas of background image keeps its aspect ratio no matter the screen size. But I'm not sure if this is causing the problem.

```
  $(window).load(function(){
      var resizeHero = function(){     
      var hero = $("#hero-fold")
      window1 = $(window);

      hero.css({
        "width": window1.width(),
        "height": "auto"
      });

    if(window1.width() < window1.height())
     {
         hero.css({
        "width": window1.width(),
        });

     }
   };

   resizeHero();

   $(window).resize(function(){
   resizeHero();    
     });
   });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you remove that javascript? If the resizing goes away, then the cause is related to it

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve? There are simple CSS solutions for maintaining a fixed aspect ratio for an element/container. Are the background images always the same size and/or aspect ratio?

Comment: I need that script there for design perspective. I tried removing it before and yes it doesn't resize anymore but then again we want it to always fill the screen no matter the viewport size.

Comment: OK, but, essentially, you want to always maintain the aspect ration (in this case 2:1 / width:height) and not 100% of the viewport width AND height, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using

> $(document).ready()

instead of load() function. Since the load() function runs only after loading the whole page, I guess that is causing problem for you.

Whereas, $(document).ready() function runs when the HTML DOM is ready.

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Mugal That did fix the issue. I also realized that the original width of the canvas is shorter than the standard viewport of 1440px.  So it shows that squished size then after a millisecond the script kicks in to resize the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with a very simple CSS trick:

```
<div class="ratio"></div>

.ratio{
  background-color: red;
  /* Setting background colour to demonstrate that the image fills the container - not needed or a requirement for the technique to work */
  background-image: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3017/3048731033_1f1fce7744_b.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* The "cover" value makes the image fill the background by it's longest axis and clips the remainder - useful for when you have images with different aspect ratios, but want to keep the container's aspect ratio */
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

By setting the height of the container to 0 and the padding-bottom (or top) to 50% (which will now be 50% of the width of the container), your container will always have an aspect ration of 2:1.

[See this codepen demo.](http://codepen.io/jayx/pen/JWXojW)

You can also use an inline image if needed, but you'll need an additional container and some positioning trickery.